# Axios latest patch is giving headaches to the developers

Tags: axios

If you are facing axios function is not found or axios.get is not a function or any other axios methods problem recently. Its not your code fault its axios developers fault, their patched have broken applications everywhere but here is a solution:

Answer (score 1):

use axios.default before any methods.
E.g axios.default.get or axios.default.patch etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).